# Where is best to get legal advice to get residency in France

Tags: france, relocation

We lived in France from 2003 until 2012. I was unfortunately in an abusive relationship so had no choice but to leave France for our safety.

I have 3 kids. 2 born in France. Their father is not on their birth certificates (his choice which I'm happy with).
Eldest son is now 19 and was born in France, we moved when he was 10. Middle child was again born in France. We moved when he was 3. Littlest was born here in the UK.

The plan has always been to move back to where we all feel is home. Financially I've not been ready. I'm very close to being ready so want to now plan making the move for early 2024.

Where am I best getting legal help please?

There are soon many options online I'm not sure where  to start looking.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to ask a lawyer. France's lawyers are grouped into geographical zone called *barreau*.
So you could look for *barreau de paris*, and use their internal search engine : https://www.avocatparis.org/annuaire.

For your case, you might filter with the *Spécialisations* field and select *droit des étrangers et de la nationalité*. This will return a list of lawyers based in the Paris area and specialized into foreigner's right.

Same might apply to other *barreaux* if you prefer (https://barreau-bordeaux.avocat.fr/ for Bordeaux for example).

As a side note, https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F295?lang=en gives some clues on what you can expect in terms of nationality for your kids.

Comment: (+1) Some additional details that do not deserve a separate answer: There is one barreau per *tribunal judiciaire* (ex-TI or TGI). Unless you know someone who is recommended for their specific expertise, it makes sense to hire a lawyer registered with the court covering the place where you will want to move because they might have a better feel for the local officials.

Answer (score 2):

@Audionuma gave a great generic answer and it would certainly be helpful to get assistance from a lawyer when you are ready to make the move.

That said, from what little information you provided, it doesn't seem like your family history would open any special path to immigration in France. Unless you are yourself a French citizen or born in France (and ignoring the father), your kids are not French citizens and do not enjoy any simplified path to French residence or citizenship. If you are British, the window to benefit from the Brexit Withdrawal agreement has already closed and I don't think you would have been covered.

This leaves the usual visa routes, e.g. through work or long-stay *visiteur* visa. You would need to qualify for those on your own merit (e.g. finding an employer ready to sponsor you) and it probably wouldn't allow your elder kid to join you.

Comment: If the father is French, would it be possible for the children to establish French citizenship by establishing paternity?  Would this require the father's consent?  Would it require amending the birth certificates?

Comment: @phoog It's complicated and I don't know all the rules. In general, amending the birth certificate is not required and French courts are reluctant to consider biological evidence (but it's changing). Traditionally, the main route to establishing paternity if the father will not affirm it would be to establish that he did behave as a father (*possession d'état*). One major use case for that is when the father is deceased. And if another man has established paternity (say the mother's husband), it may not be legally possible to reverse it, no matter how strong the evidence is.

Comment: Importantly, this will not impact citizenship if the child is older than 18 so it still wouldn't be enough for the OP's elder kid, no matter what. There are other procedural safeguards, if you want to establish paternity without the father's help (through *possession d'état* and an *acte de notoriété*), it has to happen within five years of the break up of the relationship between the father and the child. It's not completely clear from the question and presumably not something the mother is interested in at all but it also sounds like this may have happened some time ago.

Comment: https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F887?lang=en